# dax aggregate sums and counts that ignore only certain parts of the filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax, excel-2016

I have this table here:

[image: example table]

and I wanted to make a table that shows how many people in a company have an aggregate score greater than 8 for example.  So I used this formula:

```
ScoreOver8 =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( activity, activity[person] ),
            "engagement", CALCULATE ( SUM ( activity[score] ) )
        ),
        [score] > 8
    )
)
```

And this is the result:

[image: result from formula]

Now I want to add another level so I can do this:

[image: one level down]

and show which types the people that have a total score greater than 8 participated in even if they didn't earn all of that score in that type.  This isn't what happens.  What happens is:

[image: Real result one level down]

Because while on the aggregate company level there is a person in each company that earned more than 8 points, they don't necessarily earn those 8 points in any one task.

So my question is how do I make the metric so it only cares about the filter context at the company level but not at the type level so I can do what I want.

I'm using excel 2016.  I know there are a bunch of fancy new equations in power bi.  Alas. This is why I'm still at the addcolumns summarize syntax.  I wonder if I can do something like:

```
CALCULATE ( SUM ( activity[score] ), FILTER ( ALL ( [tasks] ), ... ) )
```

Too bad I only thought of trying this after I wrote out the whole question.  I'll leave it.  Maybe someone else has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to remove the type filter with ALL (or equivalently, REMOVEFITLERS).

```
ScoreOver8 =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            SUMMARIZE ( activity, activity[person] ),
            "engagement", CALCULATE ( SUM ( activity[score] ), ALL ( activity[type] ) )
        ),
        [score] > 8
    )
)
```

Comment: How if I want to keep the filter if its in the filters but not keep it if its in the rows of the pivot table

Comment: Try ALLSELECTED.